# How can I prepare well for a MSc in the UK?

Tags: masters, united-kingdom, engineering, online-resource, science

I am going to study this course in 3 months: MSc Advanced Manufacturing Technology and Systems Management. It is offered by The University of Manchester.

I am a bit nervous and I want to prepare for it to overcome my nervousness.

Are there any good resources or online courses which makes me ready for this MSc?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you nervous? If you have been accepted to the course you clearly have the pre-requisite knowledge of the subject. Take a break, have a nice holiday, relax instead.

Comment: Master's degrees in the UK are not very difficult; they are designed to take money from foreign students.  Very few people fail.  You will do fine.

Comment: @astronat I really dont know why, Bachelor was easy enough for me and I got very high scores. But I think Masters is very different.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman But The University of Manchester is not a normal university, Its rank is very high especially for engineering.

Comment: @Forenkazan I went to the University Of Oxford, and I can assure you, while the rank is high, the primary purpose of the MSc degrees is to make money from foreign students.  They are not in the business of failing people as it would hurt their income.  It doesn't mean that you will not learn anything, but keep in mind that it is not extremely difficult.  I'll write some suggestions for you anyway though, if you want to prepare.

Comment: @Forenkazan Its rank is high mostly because of its research excellence which has almost nothing to do with a master's degree, as little to none serious research goes on before Ph.D. there. I'd assure you that Captain Codeman's remark about UK universities holds for the University of Manchester too.

Comment: We can't answer the specifics about the course. However, you could email the course director (or similar person) and ask. For example, you could ask if they have a reading list that they could send you before you start. They'll probably be pleased that you're keen, and while they might not have anything useful to say, they are very unlikely to be upset by the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few tips if you want to be proactive:

- Find out what topics will be covered in the course, and start reading some of the topics which interest you.  See if there are any websites on the university that list the topics offered, and if you can access any of the learning materials.
- Reach out to some the professors and start talking to them.  (This will also be helpful later when you select a thesis)
- Reach out to previous students; ask for previous years' books and materials.  (Tip: There will probably a facebook group for everybody that does the course for a given year, ask someone to add you to the previous year's group)

But remember, as I mentioned in the comments, in the UK the independent 1-year master's degrees are set up primarily for foreign students as an income stream.  I saw this first hand when I did a master's degree in Oxford.  It is not good for business for them to fail students, so there will be a lot of support available.  So while there is no need to become complacent, I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: Surely the OP will know what topics are to be studied as that is why they chose the course? However, I agree further reading or preparatory reading is a good idea.